Why did the deities say so regarding Shachi devi?
In Mahabharata the story of Nahusha..Nahusha becomes Indra and asks Sachi devi to approach him..First Gods say she is wife of Purandara hence stay away..But Nahusha pressures the Devatas..Meanwhile Shachi Devi takes refuge of Vrihaspati ji..But devas ask Vrihaspati ji to hand over Shachi(to Nahusha)..The devas say that Nahusha is superior to Indra in Power now hence accept Nahusha as husband..(Indra was hiding due to sin of Brahminicide)..My question is why did deities ask Shachi devi to accept Nahusha wasnt she married to Purandara..was it allowed to accept a second husband?(As it was allowed in some cases like husband is impotent degraded due to sin renounced etc  also in narada smriti it is mentioned that Prajapati has allowed women to chose a superior husband compared to present inferior one)..Did the deities say adharma due to fear of Nahusha? Or was it permitted for Shachi devi to accept Nahusha as her second husband?

In the Mahabharata, the story of Nahusha and Shachi Devi (also known as Indrani) is complex and involves various moral and dharmic dilemmas. To address your questions:
Context of the Story
Indra, the king of the gods, incurred the sin of brahminicide (killing a Brahmin) and had to go into hiding to atone for his sin. During his absence, Nahusha, a human king with great merits, was elevated to the position of Indra by the other gods due to his extraordinary power and virtue.
Nahusha’s Desire for Shachi
Once in power, Nahusha became arrogant and desired Shachi Devi, Indra’s wife. He pressured the gods to persuade Shachi to accept him as her husband.
##The Gods’ Response
The gods were placed in a difficult situation due to Nahusha’s newfound power and influence. They initially defended Shachi's position as Indra’s wife, but under Nahusha’s increasing pressure, they advised her to accept him, citing his superior power at that moment.
Shachi’s Refuge with Brihaspati
Shachi Devi sought refuge with Brihaspati, the guru of the gods, who assured her of a plan to overcome Nahusha's advances.
Interpretation of the Deities' Actions

Fear of Nahusha’s Power: The gods’ suggestion to Shachi can be seen as a pragmatic response to Nahusha's dominance. Nahusha had become immensely powerful, and the gods might have feared the consequences of opposing him directly.

Dharmic Considerations: In ancient texts, there are references to situations where a woman could accept another husband under specific circumstances, such as the impotence, degradation, or prolonged absence of her current husband. The gods might have referred to these exceptions to justify their stance.

Strategic Compliance: By advising Shachi to comply, the gods might have been buying time to devise a plan to overthrow Nahusha and restore Indra. This strategy eventually worked, as Nahusha’s arrogance led to his downfall.

Adharma or Dharma?: The gods’ advice might appear adharma (unrighteous), but it can be interpreted as a nuanced response to an extraordinary situation. It reflects the complexity of dharma, which often requires weighing immediate actions against long-term consequences.


Conclusion
The deities' advice to Shachi Devi to accept Nahusha was influenced by a combination of fear, strategic necessity, and dharmic interpretations. Shachi, however, with the help of Brihaspati, managed to resist Nahusha until his arrogance led to his downfall. The narrative underscores the complexities of dharma and the difficult choices faced by both mortals and gods in the epics.
In the Mahabharata, the story of Nahusha and Shachi Devi is detailed in the Udyoga Parva and Vana Parva. These sections describe Nahusha's rise to power, his desire for Shachi, and the complex moral dilemmas faced by the gods. The narrative explores themes of dharma, power, and the eventual downfall of Nahusha due to his arrogance, guided by Brihaspati's wisdom. For detailed study, refer to these Parvas in the critical edition of the Mahabharata.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
